# Java: automatic repeating print statement

Tags: java, while-loop

I have this piece of code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int b = 3;
    int c = 5;
    char mov;
    while(b != c) {
        System.out.println("Your next move?");
        mov = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.println(mov);
    }
}
}
```

and the output:

```
Your next move?
b
b
Your next move?


Your next move?


Your next move?
```

why `Your next move?` is printed 3 times in a row without other codes in while loop be executed?

Comment: Also, you have an inifinite loop. `b` and `c` are never changed in the loop.

Comment: i know the infinite loop, it's a piece of my bigger program, it has the same problem, I just made a small sample to show the problem.

Comment: It is a duplicate. Read the answers of the duplicate question. What you typed is not just the letter b. It's the letter b, followed by a carriage return, followed by a line feed. Just print the integer (i.e. not cast to char) value of the integer value that System.in.read() returns.

Comment: sr I missed that, but you already explained it clearly. Tks!